# Can't run test script

Tags: android, typescript, automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io

FYI, I have a script for running login testcase to apps, I used typescript as a languange and appium for running the test. Also I used emulator for running the apps. **But** I faced some bug, accidentaly my script didn't run, when I hit `npm run login` it just opened and running the apps but didn't execute the login script.

Here my login-script (1login.spec.ts)

```
import LandingScreen from '../../../src/screenobjects/auth/landingScreen'
import LoginScreen from '../../../src/screenobjects/auth/loginScreen'
import SecurityCodeScreen from '../../../src/screenobjects/auth/securitycodeScreen'
import OtpScreen from '../../../src/screenobjects/auth/otpScreen'
import Gestures from '../../../src/helper/Gestures'
import { pause } from '../../../src/helper/Commands'
import { account } from '../../data-test/dte.data'
//const dataTest = require('../../data-test/dte.data')

it('I am on the landing 1 Ayo SRC Toko', async () => {
    await LandingScreen.waitForPage1Shown()
    await LandingScreen.landingPage1()
    await LandingScreen.landingPage2()
    await LandingScreen.landingPage3()
})

it('I swipe up and system displays landing 2, I click button Masuk Sekarang', async () => {
    await Gestures.swipeUpCustom()
    await LandingScreen.waitForPage2Shown()
    await Gestures.swipeUpCustom()
    await LandingScreen.landingDone()
})

it('I am on the login screen Ayo SRC Toko', async () => {
    await LoginScreen.loginTokoPage()
})

it('I login with phone number', async () => {
    await LoginScreen.loginToko({ phonenumber: account.phonenumber4 })
    await LoginScreen.masuk()
})

it('I input security code and submit', async () => {
    await SecurityCodeScreen.inputSecurityCode({ sc1: '1', sc2: '5', sc3: '0', sc4: '4', sc5: '1', sc6: '7' })
    // await SecurityCodeScreen.submit()
})

it('I input otp and submit', async () => {
    await pause(10000)
    await OtpScreen.inputOtp({ otp1: '1', otp2: '2', otp3: '3', otp4: '4', otp5: '5', otp6: '6' })
    // await OtpScreen.inputOtp({ otp1: '1', otp2: '2', otp3: '3', otp4: '4', otp5: '5', otp6: '6' })
})

it('System should be leading to Home screen', async () => {
    await pause(10000)
    // await BerandaScreen.tutorial()
    // await BerandaScreen.waitForAvatarShown()
    // await TabBar.waitForTabBarShown()
})
```

And here my webdriver config (wdio.conf.ts)

```
import type { Options } from '@wdio/types'
const path = require('path')
const androidAppPath = path.join(process.cwd(), "/src/apps/QA-AYO-TOKO-ID_v54_20231024.apk")
export const config: Options.Testrunner = {
    runner: 'local',
    autoCompileOpts: {
        autoCompile: true,
        tsNodeOpts: {
            project: './tsconfig.json',
            transpileOnly: true
        }
    },

    port: 4723,
    
    suites: {
        login: [
            './test/step-definitions/auth/1login.spec.ts',
        ],
    },
    capabilities: [{
        platformName: 'Android',
        maxInstances: 1,
        'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel 2 API 34',
        'appium:platformVersion': '14.0',
        'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
        'appium:app': androidAppPath,
    }],

    logLevel: 'info',
    
    bail: 0,
    
    baseUrl: '',
    
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    
    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    
    services: ['appium'],

    framework: 'mocha',
    
    reporters: [
        'spec',
        ['junit', {
            outputDir: './reports/junit',
            outputFileFormat: function (options) { // optional
                return `results-${options.cid}.${new Date().toDateString()}.xml`
            }
        }],
        ['allure', {
            outputDir: './reports/allure-results',
            disableWebdriverStepsReporting: false,
            disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
            useCucumberStepReporter: true,
        }],
        ['video', {
            outputDir: "./reports/video",
            saveAllVideos: true, // If true, also saves videos for successful test cases
            videoSlowdownMultiplier: 50, // Higher to get slower videos, lower for faster videos [Value 1-100]
        }],
    ],
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000
    },
}
```

After open the apps, it should be running the script but it only open the apps without running the login-script

And here what it looks like in command line (there is no error actually)

```
name@Names-MacBook-Air ayo-toko % npm run login

> ayo-toko-mocha@1.0.0 login
> wdio run ./wdio.conf.ts --suite login


Execution of 1 workers started at 2023-11-23T03:15:16.546Z

2023-11-23T03:15:16.578Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2023-11-23T03:15:16.580Z INFO @wdio/appium-service: Will spawn Appium process: node /Users/name/Documents/Project SRC/ayo-toko/node_modules/appium/index.js --base-path /
2023-11-23T03:15:19.713Z INFO @wdio/appium-service: Appium started with ID: 58003
2023-11-23T03:15:19.716Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2023-11-23T03:15:19.717Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: run,./wdio.conf.ts,--suite,login
[0-0] 2023-11-23T03:15:20.616Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] RUNNING in Android - file:///Users/name/Documents/Project%20SRC/ayo-toko/test/step-definitions/auth/1login.spec.ts
[0-0] 2023-11-23T03:15:22.164Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
[0-0] 2023-11-23T03:15:22.164Z INFO @wdio/utils: Connecting to existing driver at http://127.0.0.1:4723/
[0-0] 2023-11-23T03:15:22.202Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/session
[0-0] 2023-11-23T03:15:22.202Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
[0-0]       platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]       'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel 2 API 34',
[0-0]       'appium:platformVersion': '14.0',
[0-0]       'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
[0-0]       'appium:app': '/Users/name/Documents/Project SRC/ayo-toko/src/apps/QA-AYO-TOKO-ID_v54_20231024.apk'
[0-0]     },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]     'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel 2 API 34',
[0-0]     'appium:platformVersion': '14.0',
[0-0]     'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
[0-0]     'appium:app': '/Users/name/Documents/Project SRC/ayo-toko/src/apps/QA-AYO-TOKO-ID_v54_20231024.apk'
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
```